# Using convolution to find the density of $Z = X+Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following problem, and I might have been staring at this a bit too long because now it is all really confusing:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables such that $X \in U(0,1)$ and $Y \in U(0, \alpha)$. Find the density function of $Z = X+Y$. (Hint: Note that there are two cases, $\alpha \geq 1$ and $\alpha < 1$.)

Now, suppose I have computed the case where $\alpha < 1$ and the case where $\alpha \geq 1$ (I think I have managed to do that or at least I am on my way), do I simply add these two cases together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You should say if $\alpha\geq 1$ then .......... And if $\alpha<1$ then.........

Comment: (-1). Are you saying "yes" to "add these two cases together"? If $\alpha=2$, say, then we have $Y$ being $U(0, 2)$. If $\alpha=0.5$, then we have $Y$ being $U(0, 0.5)$. $X$ in both cases are standard uniform. We consider $X + Y$ for the two cases of $\alpha$. Why should we add them?

Comment: I think I explained what I mean, and I think he understand. Also i don't think he means to actually add them (add as +). So I think I will keep the answer.